# Insert query for specifies columns in Access VBA gives error "3061" - Too few parameters

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to add a field into a field and then insert value only to that particular field in VBA. It throws an error : Error 3061 - Too few parameters

Below is the code and query used.

```
Public Sub Yearanddate()
Dim strsql As String
Dim curnt_yearanddate As Variant
Dim curnt_year As Variant
Dim curnt_month As Variant
curnt_yearanddate = Date
Debug.Print curnt_yearanddate
curnt_year = Year(curnt_yearanddate)
curnt_month = month(curnt_yearanddate)


If (curnt_month = 5) Then
Debug.Print CreateCSField("tblmayscores", "ControlShipping") # this is working fine/creates field

strsql = "INSERT INTO tblmayscores(ControlShipping )SELECT Count([Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier DUNS Code]) AS [CountOfSupplier DUNS Code]FROM [Control Shipping Summary Report] INNER JOIN tblmayscores ON [Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier DUNS Code] = tblmayscores.[Supplier DUNS] WHERE ((([Control Shipping Summary Report].YearofProblemcaseNumber)= curnt_year) AND (([Control Shipping Summary Report].MonthofProblemcaseNumber)= curnt_month)) OR ((([Control Shipping Summary Report].YearofProblemcaseNumber)= curnt_year-1)) GROUP BY [Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier Location Code]"

CurrentDb.Execute strsql
End If

Debug.Print month(curnt_yearanddate)
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a "Group By" on an "Insert Into" statement. I also think it's best to avoid using Joins on an Insert Into statement. Why do you need to create the field on the fly? That's a "code smell". I suspect you are adding columns/fields for years or months which is never a good idea!

Comment: Are there other fields in `tblmayscores` (assuming it already exists)? Does the SQL work if copied and run within access manually? If not double check the field names are correct.

Comment: Please separate your SQL statement into bits and then reference them together. It will be much easier to locate the mistake and easier to work with in future in case something needs to change.